# Неявное преобразование типа в string C#

Tags: c#

```
public static implicit operator string(T[] arr)
    {
        string s = "[ ";
        foreach (var elem in arr)
        {
            s += elem + ", ";
        }
        s += s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2) + "]";
        return s;
    }
```

У меня есть шаблонный массив. Необходимо сделать неявное преобразование массива в тип string. Но подчеркивает operator **string**.
Выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    CS0556  Определенное пользователем преобразование должно осуществлять преобразование в данный включающий тип или из данного включающего типа.

По коду ошибки ничего путнего не выдает.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: да,  оказалось необходимо преобразовать в виде public static implicit operator string

Comment: ок, удалил ответ, как бесполезный